# Spherical functions in the space of functions on real Grassmannians

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, grassmannians, symmetric-spaces

Let $G=O(n)$ be the orthogonal group. Let $K=S(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ be the subgroup of $O(n)$.
Then the pair $(G,K)$ is symmetric, and the homomogeneous space $G/K$ is the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It is well known that the representation of $G$ in $L^2(G/K)$ is multiplicity free (since $(G,K)$ is a symmetric pair), and all irreducible $G$-submodules can be parameterized explicitly in terms of highest weights of $G$.

Moreover each such irreducible $G$-submodule contains a unique (up to proportionality) non-zero $K$-invariant vector.

**Can one write an explicit formula for this $K$-invariant vector as a function on the Grassmannian?**

Comment: I think searching for "generalized Jacoby polynomials" + "Grassmannians" might hit some results.